# Shareholders meetings -- the announcement of significant news

Tags: stocks

I'm wondering how often companies use share holder meetings to announce significant news if they have some, things like dividend changes or stock buy backs -- things that are off the official ballot.

Do companies generally stay very narrow to topic at shareholders' meetings -- following the agenda -- or do they at times use this forum to announce news that may affect a shareholder, that isn't voted on / on the ballot?

Thanks

Comment: I talked with my broker regarding this and they said that a company cannot release any significant news in a share-holder meeting that is not publicly accessible / open, similar to how earnings releases are available to the entire public at the same time, not just to a few attending a meeting.

Comment: go ahead and put that as an answer

Comment: @RayK Add your comment as an answer and please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

SE:Personal Finance user Ray K says in a comment on this question that his or her broker said:

> a company cannot release any significant news in a share-holder meeting that is not publicly accessible / open, similar to how earnings releases are available to the entire public at the same time, not just to a few attending a meeting.